# AngularJS: from .json to js/html

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I've some problems importing datas from a .json file in internet to an array.
This is the situation: I have to create an html app that imports some datas by an api (.json) on a website, store them in an array, and then show them in a chart.
The problem is that I need to pass two values in my datas request, so that I can receive only the datas linked to them.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post some code? I don't know exactly what your problem is, you can pass an object in your request with any value that you would need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading json file below solution should help:-
[How to display data from a json file in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316580/how-to-display-data-from-a-json-file-in-angularjs/28316968#28316968)

Which is as simple as:-

```
 $timeout(function(){
   dbService.getUrl('/js/udata.json').then(function(resp){
    $scope.todo=resp;
   });},1);
```

For your question "The problem is that I need to pass two values in my datas request, so that I can receive only the datas linked to them", probably if you can furnish some more details/specifics of requirement then we can help.

**Update**:

Here is the code which works for me:-

My javascript:-

```
        var todoApp= angular.module('todoApp',[]);

        todoApp.factory('dbService', ['$q','$http',function ($q , $http) {  
            var service ={};
            service.localCache = {hasdata:false,data:{},lastLoaded:new Date()};

                service.getUrl = function (urlToGet,burstCache) {
                    var svc=this;

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    if ((!burstCache)&&(svc.localCache)&&(svc.localCache.hasdata)) {
                            console.log('resolve from local cache');
                            return(svc.localCache.data);
                    }else{
                    var responsePromise = $http.get(urlToGet);

                    responsePromise.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                        svc.localCache={}; 
                        svc.localCache.hasdata=true; 
                        svc.localCache.data=data; 
                        svc.localCache.lastLoaded= new Date(); 
                        deferred.resolve(data); 
                        console.log('resolve from ajax') });

                    responsePromise.error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                        deferred.reject({ error: "Ajax Failed", errorInfo: data }); svc.localCache={}; });
                    }
                    return (deferred.promise);
                }

                return service;
                }]);

        todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", ['$scope','$timeout','dbService',function($scope, $timeout, dbService)
        {
            $scope.todo={};

          $timeout(function(){
           dbService.getUrl('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=35&lon=139&cnt=10&mode=json',true).then(function(resp){
            $scope.todo=resp;
           });},1);
        }]);
```

Here's my HTML:-

```
<body >
<div ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
    <div>
    <p>City : {{todo.city.name}}</p>
    <p>Country : {{todo.city.country}}</p>
    <p>Population : {{todo.city.population}}</p>
    <p>COD : {{todo.cod}}</p>
    </div>
    <table border="1"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Dt</th>
        <th>Pressure</th>
        <th>Humidity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="t in todo.list">
                <td>{{ t.dt }}</td>
                <td>{{ t.pressure }}</td>
                <td>{{ t.humidity }}</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: I need to search for a specific city, so I have to pass to the function a longitude and a latitude values.
The link is like this: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=35&lon=139&cnt=10&mode=json
The two values in the link are the two I need to pass.

Comment: The example in my link above should work for you, just the difference is your request is $http.jsonp(...) because it is a cross site request. Let me come up with a sample code for you. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I just updated the code where I am able to display the data from your mentioned url. The data returned is simple JSON so no need to do JsonP.  I hope this helps. Kindly mark as answer if it is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thanks to you too!